# Goroutine is taking same time to execute my function as for loop

Tags: go, concurrency

I have a function to create Istio VirtualService objects.
I am using goroutines to execute my function concurrently, starting 100 workers.

```
            var data map[string]string
            for _, data = range MapList {
                wg.Add(1)
                limit.Execute(func() {
                    go func(data map[string]string) {
                        defer wg.Done()
                        _,_ = m.createVirtualServices(ctx, data, namespace)
                    }(data)
                })
                wg.Wait()
            }
```

this takes exact same time to execute if I'd just loop over seMapList and execute my function.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Burak Serdan answer is right but probably not in this case. From what I see you pass annonymous function to `limit.Execute` so your annonymous function will really start new goroutine but not immediatelly but after `limit.Execute` will call this annonymous function somewhere inside.

But instead of passing N annonymous functions you can pass one function which will then fun N goroutines

```
var data map[string]string

limit.Execute(func() {
    for _, data = range MapList {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(data map[string]string) {
            defer wg.Done()
            _,_ = m.createVirtualServices(ctx, data, namespace)
        }(data)
    }
})
wg.Wait()
```

Comment: thanks let me try and I will report

Comment: @Arsen Does this help to reduce time?

Answer (score 4):

Because you are waiting for the goroutine to complete right after you start it. Try this instead:

```
            for _, data = range MapList {
                wg.Add(1)
                limit.Execute(func() {
                    go func(data map[string]string) {
                        defer wg.Done()
                        _,_ = m.createVirtualServices(ctx, data, namespace)
                    }(data)
                })
            }
            wg.Wait() // Wait for them after all goroutines are created
```

Comment: I can see that my function executing now differently, not in order of the mapList, but objects getting created with diff time. Still takes same amount of time

Comment: 1min13s - same time recorded with for loop

Comment: but I'll accept it as the correct answer, because it did the trick. but maybe it's due to kube-api server client throttling

Comment: limit.Execute is probably synchronous. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69359178/12301864